# ASP.net mvc не запускает приложение

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

При попытке скомпилировать представления *VS* выдает вот такую ошибку:

> Описание: Ошибка во время компиляции ресурса, необходимого для обслуживания этого запроса. Просмотрите следующие сведения о данной ошибке и измените соответственно исходный код.
>
> Сообщение об ошибке компилятора: CS0234: Имя типа или пространства имен "Ajax" отсутствует в пространстве имен "System.Web.Mvc" (пропущена ссылка на сборку?)

Ошибка источника:

```
Строка 22:     using System.Web.WebPages;
Строка 23:     using System.Web.Mvc;
Строка 24:     using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Строка 25:     using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
Строка 26:     using System.Web.Routing;
```

хотя в using у меня есть `using System.Web.Mvc;`

что это может быть?

Приложение не делает ничего, оно должно просто сгенерировать страничку.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804198/ajax-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc

Comment: @Igor переведите ответ. ответы-ссылки в комменах - зло :)

Answer (score 2):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804198/ajax-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc

Перевожу:

У Вас подключена старая версия System.Web.Mvc.dll, в которой отсутствует namespace System.Web.Mvc.Ajax.

Выберите эту dll в дереве Solution и проверьте номер версии в Properties.

Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши в панели Solution и выберите "Manage NuGet Packages", найдите ASP.NET MVC и нажмите Install.

Comment: Версия v4.0.30319

Comment: как установить новую версию?

Comment: Это версия .NET Runtime, а не ASP.NET MVC. Добавил.

Comment: ну а как добавить а как посмотреть версию ASP.MVC

Comment: В Properties System.Web.Mvc.dll  есть строчка Version. Что там написано?